# Google scripts. How to transfer a range of data from a master sheet to other tabs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I don't really do AppScript but I am trying to help my dad out with some of his workload.
Essentially he starts with a spreadsheet that has sales reps, assistant sales reps, customer number and the customer name. He wants this script to make a separate spreadsheet sheet for each assistant sales rep and their customers. Essentially just pasting a range of cells into each tab.
I have created functions to make an array of assistant sales reps and to make tabs that are named for each assistant sales rep. I am however am drawing a blank when it comes to finding the beginning and end of each sales rep on the sheet, then pasting it over to their tab.
Below is an example of how the sheet is laid out: All of the rows are thankfully ordered by ASR.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhbDr.png)

```
function importThisOne() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  let sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  // change this value for different columns (1 = A, 2 = B... etc)
  let column = "2";
  // gets the name of the active sheet for later use
  let mainTableName = sheet.getName();

  let range = sheet.getRange("E2");
  range.setValue(mainTableName);

  // calls the columnList function and returns it here
  let list = columnList(sheet, column);

  // calls the makeTabsFromList and passes the list and the spreadsheet object
  makeTabsfromList(ss, list);

  transferDataToTab(list, ss, sheet)

}
```

```
function columnList(activeSheet, column) {
  let lastColumn = activeSheet.getLastRow();
  let list = new Array();
// Loops through to make a list of each ASR's   
  for (let i = 1; i < lastColumn; i++)
  {
    let duplicate = false;
    let currentValue = activeSheet.getRange(i+1, column).getValue();

    if (list.includes(currentValue))
    {
      duplicate = true;
    }

    if (duplicate === false)
    {
      list.push(currentValue);
    }
  }

 // returns list of unique values
  return list;
}
```

```
function makeTabsfromList(spreadSheet, list)
{
  for (let i = 0; i <= list.length; i++)
  {
    spreadSheet.insertSheet(list[i]);
  }
}
```

This is a list of all functions I have so far, and am really unsure of how to tackle this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will collect all of the rows and depending upon the value in column one which I assume is the sheet name it distributes each of the arrays of rows to it's respective named sheet.  It will also create the sheets if they are not already there.  If the are no headers in the sheet the first time it will place the headers there as well.

```
function myfunk00() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//edit sheet name
  const sr = 2;//edit data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();//This could be modified to get data only over a hand selected range. The activerange.
  const hr = 1;//header row
  const hs = sh.getRange(hr,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const shOb = vs.reduce((a,r,i) => {
    let p = r[0];
    if(!a.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      a[p] = [r];
      a.pA.push(p);
    } else {
      a[p].push(r);
    }
    return a;
  },{pA:[]});
  shOb.pA.forEach(p => {
    let s;
    s = ss.getSheetByName(p);
    if(!s) {
      s = ss.insertSheet(p);
    } 
    let lr = s.getLastRow();
    if(!lr) {
      shOb[p].unshift(hs);
      s.getRange(1,1,shOb[p].length,shOb[p][0].length).setValues(shOb[p]);
    } else {
      s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, shOb[p].length,shOb[p][0].length).setValues(shOb[p]);
    }
  })
}
```

Sheet0: Data

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet1 | B2 | C2 | D2 |
| Sheet2 | B3 | C3 | D3 |
| Sheet3 | B4 | C4 | D4 |
| Sheet1 | B5 | C5 | D5 |
| Sheet2 | B6 | C6 | D6 |
| Sheet3 | B7 | C7 | D7 |
| Sheet1 | B8 | C8 | D8 |
| Sheet2 | B9 | C9 | D9 |
| Sheet3 | B10 | C10 | D10 |
| Sheet1 | B11 | C11 | D11 |
| Sheet2 | B12 | C12 | D12 |
| Sheet3 | B13 | C13 | D13 |
| Sheet1 | B14 | C14 | D14 |
| Sheet2 | B15 | C15 | D15 |
| Sheet3 | B16 | C16 | D16 |
| Sheet1 | B17 | C17 | D17 |
| Sheet2 | B18 | C18 | D18 |
| Sheet3 | B19 | C19 | D19 |
| Sheet1 | B20 | C20 | D20 |
| Sheet2 | B21 | C21 | D21 |
| Sheet3 | B22 | C22 | D22 |
| Sheet1 | B23 | C23 | D23 |
| Sheet2 | B24 | C24 | D24 |
| Sheet3 | B25 | C25 | D25 |

Sheet1:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet1 | B2 | C2 | D2 |
| Sheet1 | B5 | C5 | D5 |
| Sheet1 | B8 | C8 | D8 |
| Sheet1 | B11 | C11 | D11 |
| Sheet1 | B14 | C14 | D14 |
| Sheet1 | B17 | C17 | D17 |
| Sheet1 | B20 | C20 | D20 |
| Sheet1 | B23 | C23 | D23 |

Sheet2:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Sheet2 | B3 | C3 | D3 |
| Sheet2 | B6 | C6 | D6 |
| Sheet2 | B9 | C9 | D9 |
| Sheet2 | B12 | C12 | D12 |
| Sheet2 | B15 | C15 | D15 |
| Sheet2 | B18 | C18 | D18 |
| Sheet2 | B21 | C21 | D21 |
| Sheet2 | B24 | C24 | D24 |

If you wish you can do both reps and assistant reps at the same time with this sort of approach:

```
function myfunk00() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");//edit sheet name
  const sr = 2;//edit data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  const hr = 1;//header row
  const hs = sh.getRange(hr, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues().flat();
  const shOb = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    let ps = r.slice(0, 2);
    ps.forEach(p => {
      if (!a.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
        a[p] = [r];
        a.pA.push(p);
      } else {
        a[p].push(r);
      }
    })
    return a;
  }, { pA: [] });
  shOb.pA.forEach(p => {
    let s;
    s = ss.getSheetByName(p);
    if (!s) {
      s = ss.insertSheet(p);
    }
    let lr = s.getLastRow();
    if (!lr) {
      shOb[p].unshift(hs);
      s.getRange(1, 1, shOb[p].length, shOb[p][0].length).setValues(shOb[p]);
    } else {
      s.getRange(s.getLastRow() + 1, 1, shOb[p].length, shOb[p][0].length).setValues(shOb[p]);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: wow! looks good, the only issue is that what instead of it trying to split data from column A (sales Rep). I need to split it from column B (Assistant sales rep).

Comment: Then let `p = r[1]`